# google adsense report automation script - need user for sign-in

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, adsense

i've been working on an automation script for adsense (admob) report download automation, I had a whole script done which used custom direct http calls to the api, however when analyzing the error code I came to know that service api worker accounts can't access the "personal" data which are reports apparently. Whats the best way to automate the download or reports without having human interference ever( or almost never )? I've checked out the documentation for the php api library tat google supplies, but the api is  outdated - last update was 5 years ago.

https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/
if you go to client libraries-> learn more -> PHP -> browse examples.

Is there any **new** and **still relevant** information that I could use to accomplish my task here?

---

**Update.
Using this code to generate the report:**

```
<?php

  require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setAuthConfig('oauth_client.json');
  $client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access
  $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
  $client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense");
  $client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/go');
  $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();

  if( isset($_GET['code'])  ){
    $code=$_GET['code'];
  }else{
    $code=null;
  }

  if(!$code){ 
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
  }else{
    $client->authenticate($code);  
    $access_token = $client->getAccessToken();  
    $client->setAccessToken($access_token);
    $adsense = new Google_Service_Adsense($client);
    $reports = $adsense->reports;
     $csv = $reports->generate('2018-08-01','2018-08-05',array("metric" => ["VIEWED_IMPRESSIONS","CLICKS","EARNINGS"],"dimension"=>["DATE", "COUNTRY_CODE","APP_NAME"],"currency"=>"EUR"));
  }
```

The code works as-is, however if I add a "alt" => "csv" parameter:

```
  $csv = $reports->generate('2018-08-01','2018-08-05',array("metric" => ["VIEWED_IMPRESSIONS","CLICKS","EARNINGS"],"dimension"=>["DATE", "COUNTRY_CODE","APP_NAME"],"currency"=>"EUR",'alt' =>'csv'));
```

the result is "blank":

```
Google_Service_AdSense_AdsenseReportsGenerateResponse Object
(
    [collection_key:protected] => warnings
    [averages] => 
    [endDate] => 
    [headersType:protected] => Google_Service_AdSense_AdsenseReportsGenerateResponseHeaders
    [headersDataType:protected] => array
    [kind] => 
    [rows] => 
    [startDate] => 
    [totalMatchedRows] => 
    [totals] => 
    [warnings] => 
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

I know about sanitizing get, don't scold me too much about it, I want to get it working first. How do add the alt = media and alt=csv parameters?

Comment: The api isnt out dated i would call it stable.  Please edit your question and include your code and describe any issues you are having with your solution.   You might also want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: well when trying to use the examples with the actual php library the class autoloader does not work, and the classes themselves are outdated.

Comment: If your saying it doesnt work please edit your question and include the code that you say is not working.  Explain to us whats not working and we can help you fix it.   Without seeing the code you are trying and seeing the errors you are getting its hard to help you.

Comment: [Adsence host](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AdSense%20Host%20API)  or [addsence managment](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/AdSense%20Management%20API)   I have some newer samples.

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Which method are you trying to use [genreate report](https://developers.google.com/adsense/host/v4.1/reports/generate)?  what error message are you getting?

Comment: I'm using adsense scope not the managment scope. But yes, I'm using the generate method. https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/blob/master/src/Google/Service/AdSense/Resource/Reports.php

Comment: I cant test it becoues i dont have an adsence host account.   But Your getting results back.  There is no error.  Have you tried adding the fields parameter to your request.

Comment: havent tried that yet, will try again

Comment: I don't have an adsense host account either, this is not a adsense-host api call.

Comment: [test here](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/adsensehost/v4.1/adsensehost.reports.generate?startDate=2018-09-01&endDate=2018-09-30&_h=3&)  I cant genreate reports.   The one under [managment api](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/reports/generate)  appears to have been deprecated.

Comment: try something like [$adsense->accounts-reports->generate](https://developers.google.com/adsense/management/v1.4/reference/accounts/reports/generate) but i am thinking most of this api is no longer supported.

Comment: I'm not trying to do account reports, I'm trying to get an admob report where the dimension is app_name, because I'm trying to get earnings based on day, country and app name. The issue here is that I'm unable to specify alt=media which would remove the limit of 100.000 rows(or something like that)... I started parsing the json result into a csv file. But I'm unable to proceed if there will be a limit on rows.. :/ Thanks for the help though.. I'll figure something out eventually and add an answer if no one will be faster than me

Comment: And you think the adsence api will give you access to admob reports?

Comment: it already does. The only issue is the row limitation and csv format.
admob is a sub-part of adsense report api -> https://developers.google.com/admob/android/reporting

Comment: I sent an email off to google to see if i can get some info on which methods actually work.  I sent a link to your question someone may or may not respond.  I have been unable to get a response either.

Comment: thanks, I added the issue on they'r github page, maybe someone will see it and give a response.